# Duplicated profiles

Tags: support, profile-page, duplicate-accounts

When I try to create a story link with ID **(yulioaj290)** for my profile, appears an error saying that these ID has been taken, however, the link (https://stackoverflow.com/story/yulioaj290) contains information about me, even info about my Aptoide account and a work writed by me. I just not remember the email I was used for this other account.

Comment: I tried to do this, but I don't know the other profile link, only the story link **[http://stackoverflow.com/story/yulioaj290](http://stackoverflow.com/story/yulioaj290)**. I really need to merge this two profiles, because the other profile have more information about my activities as developer, and is more older.

Comment: @YulioAlemanJimenez you should still follow those directions.  Just used the contact form and explain the situation.  Any support you need will need to be over a more private communication method than an open Q&A

Comment: I understand, but, as I don't know the other profile link, the contact form is showing an error. OK, I have sent a message with topic `Other`.